# calculating sha1 hash of a pass for use in puppet user type

Tags: hash, puppet

I'm new to puppet. The following is tutorial code:

```
user { '<your username>':
ensure => 'present',
groups => ['sudo'],
home => '/home/<username>',
managehome => true,
password => '$6$lY2Gp3Cr$zNrUB7T3yibUF/gWn5cTQ0fNv7MUmx/DZuw3E7I..Vh9tITG28BtgvXJPU4Gm4Z/9oNvlbX24KzQ9Ib1QH1B9.',
shell => '/bin/bash',
```

}

the password field is a hash of the string "test". What's the simplest way to derive sha1 hashes from strings? I know puppet has a specific "sha1" function, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [managing a user password for linux in puppet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114328/managing-a-user-password-for-linux-in-puppet)

Answer (score 0):

First off, that is not a sha1 hash - the `$6$` indicates sha512.

Beyond that, you should use tools such as `mkpasswd` to create hashes for you, then enter them into Puppet. The ability to include plain text passwords into your manifests or Hiera data is not especially useful.