# Password change is not working from Puppet master

Tags: puppet

I have written a `site.pp` to change a password from the puppet master. Below is the `site.pp`. It is changing the password on agent host `idrac-h868gm1`, but when I try to login with the changed password (In this case `devuser888`) it is not working.

I used single and double quotes but it still does not work. I manually changed the password to `devuser888` and it is working.

```
node default {
  class { 'ntp':
    servers => ['ntp1','ntp2']
  }
  include ntp
}
node /^(prod|dev)\d+$/ {
  include mounts
  include nis
}
node idrac-h868gm1 {
  user { 'dev':
    ensure   => present,
    password => "devuser888"
  }
}
```

> Puppet server version: 2.7.1 (open source)
>   Puppet agent version: 4.8.0
>   Puppet agent OS: RHEL7.2

Please let me know for any more info/queries

Comment: Please run the agent and add the debug logs to your question: `puppet agent -t --debug`

Comment: Hi Dominic, added debug, it si running Executing: '/usr/sbin/usermod -p devuser88 dev' and checked in shadow file, dev:devuser888:17149:0:99999:7:::. Still not working.

Comment: Please provide the entire debug logs. Passwords are not set with `usermod`, the agent will typically use ruby-shadow and so the logs may show if this isn't available or working correctly.

Comment: Please click  link to view logs.https://chelsious-my.sharepoint.com/personal/vidyasagar_asicdesigners_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=GaTobTW0sbrzL4u3oWvIZQVdjHkTGc2g1YUapTJhpAw%3d&docid=1f22eb1f7c8d54d61b5ce74553e38a694&rev=1

Answer (score 0):

> checked in shadow file, `dev:devuser888:17149:0:99999:7:::`

The passwords in the shadow file must be hashed, but this password is plain text. The `password` property of the `user` resource states that it must be the *encrypted format the local system requires* ([Resource Type Reference](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#user-attribute-password)).

Either copy the crypted version out of shadow after setting it manually and put this in your manifest (e.g. `password => '$6$.......'`), or keep the plain text version and use the `pw_hash` function from the [stdlib module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) to generate it.

For the latter, it's best if I refer to an existing answer, which shows how to use the `pw_hash` function to generate a hash: [managing a user password for linux in puppet with pw_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034759/146925).